# Voisin / avoisinant

Tags: sens, adjectifs

Quelle est la différence entre *voisin* et *avoisinant* ? Par exemples, *dents voisine*s ou *dents avoisinante*s ?

Antidote reste assez laconique sur ce sujet.

> **Avoisinant** : Proche, voisin, attenant. *Les maisons avoisinantes. Le
> quartier avoisinant*.
>
> **Voisin** : Qui est proche dans l’espace. *Nous habitons la rue voisine.
> Deux villes voisines. Un village voisin d’un parc naturel.*

D'autres dictionnaires ne sont pas plus bavards.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux adjectifs se recoupent mais je dirais que ***voisin*** est plus souvent symétrique et immédiat alors qu'***avoisinant*** décrit ce qui se trouve de manière plus large autour d'une référence, dans le voisinage.

Pour ce qui est des dents, j'entends plus parler de dents ***contiguëes*** (dents qui se touchent) que de dents voisines qui laisse peut-être plus de marge.

Les deux premières pages de recherche de **dents avoisinantes** remontent une grosse majorité de pages provenant de sites québecois. Il est donc possible que cet adjectif soit plus populaire au Québec, au moins dans ce contexte.

Comment: Oui "dents contiguës" (ou contigües) mais ça fait un peu mathématique. Il y a peut-être un terme de dentiste que je ne connais pas, mais j'aurais tendance à dire "dent(s) d'à côté".